What is the contribution of respiratory rate to oxygen absorption?
Firstly, I am aware that oxygen absorption in the alveolus is perfusion limited. Apparently, oxygen equilibrates in ~0.25 seconds or 1/3rd of the way along a pulmonary capillary.

However, we are often told that we breathe faster so we can get more oxygen during periods of high activity.
This seems to contradict the first point. If oxygen diffusion is perfusion limited then it makes sense that an increased heart rate will increase the oxygenated blood flow ($\dot{V}_{O_2}$), but an increased $P_{AO_2}$ (due to increased respiratory rate) surely makes no difference as of the blood is already totally saturated at normal $P_{AO_2}$?
What is the mistake in my understanding or analysis? Does an isolated increased respiratory rate (in the absence of increased perfusion) affect oxygen absorption?

This site requires evidence of research in an effort to solve your question. You've assumed - without explanation of why - that PAO2 remains the same with exercise. Please look at an oxygen dissociation curve to see if that helps with your confusion. If it doesn't, edit your question to include links to what you've read regarding the effect of exercise on O2 saturation. Thanks.
